# What's the difference between request and query??? Also, what's the difference between request, response, server, and client?

Tags: networking, server, request, response

Sorry, this is not a question, this is just a post for something useful that I wanted to share it with you. I didn't know the answer but I figured them out after a bit of research. So, I'm summarizing in the answer below, **ALL** the things about the difference between those terms. Feel free to copy or relaunch, because my self, I stoled them(haha) and gathered them in one place for easy reference.

Request and response seem to be having the same meaning (synonyms), especially if English isn't your native language, like me), but In fact, there's a difference between them, especially in CS and programming. You have to master the difference between them, so that you don't use them interchangeably, and know exactly how and when to use them.

Comment: This is not the place to add this. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

## What's the difference between request and query???

- First of all, **query and request can both be nouns and verbs**. E.g:

  - I requested a refund.
  - We received a request for a refund.
  - I queried the price.
  - We received a query about the price.
- To request something is to ask for something, an object or a favour etc. A request is a *polite demand*. To query is to ask about something i.e. you are ***wanting information***. *A query is a question*.
- Also, QUERY is an inquiry(*Query and inquiry are synonyms*)
  They are both requests but the difference is that the **QUERY is a precise request**. In informatics, if you need information about something you need to send a *specific* request with precise information.

"I queried information about user account Maxim Pavlov" = "I need to know about this website users. In particular, I need to know if there is any Maxim Pavlov registered on this site".

- In programming speak, specifically in database field, **A query is a result of a Select request.**
- If you are Arabic, best translations in Arabic would be, *request = طلب and query = إستعلام*)

## About the difference between request, response, client, and server

*Request*: From Client to Server

***Response***: From Server to Client

***Server***: Receive Request and Send Response

***Client***: Send Request and Receive Response

A Client (web user) makes a Request to a Server(strong computers and machines) which processes the Request, determines the appropriate Response, and delivers it back(return it) to the Client.

Comment: Servers can also send queries/requests to clients, and clients can respond to server queries/requests.